# Java not creating files in specified directory

Tags: java, file, io

This program is not creating files in the directories that I want. But when I simply create the file without specifying any paths, it works fine.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = input.nextLine();
        File newFile = new File("C:\\Users\\" + inputString + ".txt");


        if(newFile.exists() == false) {

            try {
                newFile.createNewFile();
                System.out.println(inputString + ".txt hasbeen created.");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error");
            }
        }
        else {

            System.out.println("File Already Exists");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean its not creating files? Is it throwing an error? What happens?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the exception message to see what the issue is? System.out.println(e.getMessage());

Comment: You're squelching the error, catching such a general exception can lead to confiding errors.  For debugging, try to remove the catch and let the exception new thrown.  It might say something more valuable than "error".

Comment: Where do you want to create the file?

Comment: What is the value of inputString?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might not know what a exception might be, it's an error, you want to avoid'em but in that cases the error might actually help, if you weren't throwing away all the information it has you might even had solved yourself.

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error");
}
```

the compiler might actually trying to tell you what's wrong, but you are throwing all the information away. Exception handling should be used when the error is expected and just as a valid option as the non error and you don't want your software to stop because of it. In your case, `e.printStackTrace()` might help, that way the compiler will actually print out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to create your file in the system `C:\Users`  directory. Try making your own directory for your source files (under your own home directory), instead of putting them in the system path.
You probably don't have permissions to write to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

try with printStackTrace method:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

may be java.io.IOException: Access is denied.

try with another path location or make your own directory:

```
File newFile = new File("C:\\temp\\" + inputString + ".txt");
```